# Dell Inspiron n5110 syslog ACPI warnings on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, 13.04, dell, inspiron, acpi

I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 and got a bunch of warnings in syslog:

```
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689651] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689676] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689688] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689703] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000540-0x000000000000054f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689717] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689724] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689738] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689752] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689758] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689772] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
May  9 02:21:34 Dell kernel: [    9.689785] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
```

and I would like to get rid of them, but have no clue on how...
what is ACPI and how do I get to know what device is ment from these lines?

thia,
morbus

Comment: i had the same before , but not now cat /var/log/syslog | grep ACPI  not now .... i have kernel 3.9...same model dell inspiron n5110